# Removing Breadcrumb from Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, breadcrumbs

I am making a fully customized Sharepoint, and I want to hide the breadcrumb. I tried placing visibility="false" within the Content Placeholder for the breadcrumb, but it only disables the Title and leaves the breadcrumb intact.

There were some fixes for this in 2010, etc. This required adding some CSS to the div containing the breadcrumb, but the breadcrumb is now contained in a Content Place Holder so it changes up the way to do things.

Does anyone have insight into this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 has its breadcrumb hidden by default, so I'm a little confused as to why it's visible in your solution (did you migrate from 2010?).

Anyway, settting .ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox to { display:none; } with css (which is the out-of-the-box seattle.master way of hiding the breadcrumb) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. We did update 2007->2010->2013, and many sites maintained the breadcrumbs. However the CSS entry Kimzter noted didn't work. The one that worked for us was:

.ms-pagebreadcrumb { display:none; }

This is actually one of the few places I use the Script Editor webpart, as we have a lot of sites that want to maintain the breadcrumbs, so changing the master page or master CSS wouldn't work for us.